# Foreign Key Cascade On Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume that i have the following tables

```
User,Article,Comment
```

A `User` can `Comment` on an `Article` or write an `Article`.

I wanted the behavior that:

- When i delete a `User` it should delete all of his `Articles` and
  `Comments`
- When i delete an `Article` it should delete all of its `Comments`

So i thought i should use `FOREIGN KEYS` and tried to model the above as the following

```
CREATE TABLE [User](
   UserId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   Username nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Article](
   ArticleId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   UserId int NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY(UserId) references [User](UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE [Comment](
   CommentId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   UserId int Not NULL,
   ArticleId int NOT NULL ,
   FOREIGN KEY(UserId) references [User](UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY(ArticleId) references [Article](ArticleId) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

But the problem comes with the `Comment` causing

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__Comment__Article__32E0915F' on table 'Comment' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

My question is how would you model this behavior and still use `CASCADE ON DELETE` AND `FOREIGEN KEYS`?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you probably want `Username` to have more than one character.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why not! i made it 50 to make you happy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to remove the Cascade Delete on the User Foreign Key on the Comment.

As when the user is deleted, this will cascade delete the Article, which will in turn Cascade Delete the comments:

```
CREATE TABLE [Comment](
   CommentId int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   UserId int Not NULL,
   ArticleId int NOT NULL ,
   FOREIGN KEY(UserId) references [User](UserId),
   FOREIGN KEY(ArticleId) references [Article](ArticleId) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```